# How to deploy a vaadin project on GAE?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, vaadin

I'm trying to deploy an existing `vaadin` project to `GAE`.
But I'm constantly getting an error: `ClassNotFoundException: com.vaadin.server.GAEApplicationServlet`

This is what I've done:

- commented out the `@WebServlet` annotation in my `extends UI` class
- projec properties, checked: use Google App Engine. Thereby some libraries were added to 
  my `WEB-INF/lib` folder: `gwt-servlet, jsr107, some appendine-*`.
- created the `appengine-web.xml`
- created the `web.xml`:

  ```
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>MyProject</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.vaadin.server.GAEApplicationServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>UI</param-name>
          <param-value>de.mypath.ApplicationUI</param-value>
      </init-param>
  </servlet>
  ```

`<servlet-mapping>`
`<servlet-name>MyProject</servlet-name>`
`<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`
`</servlet-mapping>`

I can run my project fine if I use `com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet` and run on a local tomcat.
But running on a jetty GAE (or also deploying in the cloud) I get the `ClassNotFountException` mentioned above.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've used GAE, but when I was it seemed like I had to add some jars to WEB-INF/lib myself, despite everything working fine locally.  Later I would get warnings about those same jars, but if I removed them I'ld get NoClassDefFoundException again.

Comment: The complained class is from vaadin-servlet.jar. I already copied it (among all other libraries) in the WEB-INF/lib folder for testing this, but did not change anything...

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is some classes are not allowed in GAE, though it seems GAEApplicationServlet, given the name shouldn't be referencing any of those.  How new is the latest vaadin-servlet.jar?  Maybe try the previous version?

Comment: using 7.1.1, also tried 7.1.0. But cannot go back further as I use Servlet 3.0, which is not supported prior...

Answer (score 0):

Copying ***vaadin-server-7.5.10.jar*** to WEB-INF/lib and using ***`com.vaadin.server.GAEVaadinServlet`*** instead of `com.vaadin.server.GAEApplicationServlet` has resolved the issue.